# Why lag is occured in my WEB page when only scroll down to bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm making my web page with React, GSAP, scss and etc...

But when I build my code and scroll down to bottom of page, It occurs some lags.

The first time when i met that lag, I guess the cause of lag is my background image size(600kb?) and i reduce my background image to 400kb.

Unfortunately, the lag is occured continuously...

So, I wanna know what is the cause of this lag and how can i remove that.

[LINK of my web-page](https://goseungduk.github.io/)

[source of my web-page](https://github.com/goseungduk/goseungduk.github.io)

Because this web page was made yesterday, There are no many features.

plz tell me why this phenomenon is occured :)

Comment: I've been open your website but i didn't see any issues like lag etc. Please Make sure that you're not getting cached or open your web on New Incognito Window or use updated browser, maybe your browser not supported some code or etc.

Comment: @HelloPutra Exactly! the issue i mentioned isn't watched when i use Edge browser. I used to Chrome of version  91.0.4472.114 is the newest. What browser you use???

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with your browser but I use Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 too btw.

Comment: @HelloPutra hmm... Okay thank you for sharing your experience :) plz post your answer to below.

Comment: I'm afraid that your lag problem is from your scrolling animation that you made for. I suggest you to use react-scroll or etc.

Comment: @HelloPutra Because when I use `react-scroll` the same issue is occured, I made scroll logic manually. Maybe my computer specification is problem

Comment: Hmm, please check your chrome hardware acceleration and make sure it's on.

Comment: @HelloPutra Oh! As soon as turn on `hardware acceleration`, the issue is removed. thank you hhhhh

Comment: @HelloPutra My laptop has no gpu and has only i5 7th Gen cpu. Is this related with this?

Comment: I didn't know thats was related or not to GPU but I think chrome hardware acceleration it's on automatically and Im happy that your problem was fixed =))

Comment: @HelloPutra post your comment to below and I'll choose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your chrome hardware acceleration and make sure it's on =))